# Issues with building and running junit test files with command line

Tags: java, command-line, junit

I have .java files and their .class files, along with junit test files, and junit-4.10.jar and hamcrest-core-1.3.jar in the same folder. I am trying to build it by doing the following:

> javac ErrorTest*.java

I get a lot of errors saying

> error: package org.junit does not exist

Then when I try to use the junit file in the /usr/share/java folder using this command:

> javac -cp /usr/share/java/* ErrorTest*.java

I get the following error:

> javac: invalid flag: /usr/share/java/ant-antlr-1.9.6.jar Usage: javac
>     use -help for a list of possible options

How can I build and run these ErrorTest.java junit files?

Edit: Ok, I figured it out but I don't understand why.

The following gives me errors:

```
javac -classpath /path/to/graph/*:/path/to/graph/lib/* ErrorTest*.java
```

The following produces the desired .class files:

```
javac -classpath .:/path/to/graph/*:/path/to/graph/lib/* ErrorTest*.java
```

Could anyone explain why ".:" works? Much thanks.

Comment: It seems you are missing the dependency jar

Comment: if I include junit.jar in the classpath using -cp /usr/share/java/* or copy a junit.jar into the working directory, I still get the error: package org.junit does not exist. I don't know why it cannot find junit.jar...

Comment: are you using any IDE? or using text editor and command line

Comment: Only text editor and command line.

Comment: It is better go with some Ide to overcome this kind of error. you have to lot of configuration on plain text file and cmdline which is taken care by IDE itself. Why don't try with eclipse or other IDE

Comment: @SMANSARI Yeah... thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its becasue,Java CLASSPATH points to current directory denoted by `"."` and it will look for classes in the current directory.

In case we have multiple directories defined in CLASSPATH variable, Java will look for a class starting from the first directory and only look the second directory in case it did not find the specified class in the first directory. Multiple directories are added in classpath with the help of `":"`

you have set classpath like

```
javac -classpath .:/path/to/graph/*:/path/to/graph/lib/* ErrorTest*.java
```

so using this command you are setting multiple directories in classpath.

**JVM search directory in the order they have listed in CLASSPATH variable.**

In your case seems some classes are present in the current directory so if you are not providing current directory in classpath JVM searches in second path and then third but required class is not present so seems that it is not working

Answer (score 0):

For Running Junit 4.x test cases from command prompt you should use below command

```
java -cp C:\lib\junit.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore [test class name]
```

For running Junit 3.x test cases from command prompt you need use below command

```
java -cp /usr/java/lib/junit.jar junit.textui.TestRunner [test class name]
```

Example Program

```
**TestCaseA.java**
package test;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;


    public class TestCaseA
    {
       @Before
       public void beforeMethod()
       {
           System.out.println("Before method..");
       }

       @Test
       public void JUnit4Test()
       {
          System.out.println("In test method");
       }

       @After
       public void afterMethod()
       {
          System.out.println("after method");
       }
    }
```

Execution from command prompt

```
java -cp junit-4.10.jar;test\TestCaseA.class; org.junit.runner.JUnitCore test.TestCaseA
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. However, my issue was how to build the .java file.

Comment: I've updated my question to add more content and clarification.